# read clipboard execCommand('copy') js

Tags: javascript, execcommand

I copied the div content with bold text. I want to read the output 'foo'. I want to show the text console with html tags.

```
CONSOLE
<b>foo</b>
```

not only show TRUE in console.. =/

http://jsfiddle.net/u9g3vg7b/2/

Comment: Boolean is the expected return value, if you want to access the text which was copied, you will have to read it another way, or perhaps use the past command on something. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy

Comment: tks @alexander-omara .. but,  I am a layman on the subject, how do I get the result?

Comment: @Isaac will take a look... tks